# CodeIgniter set smtp email globally for version 2.1.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my one of project CodeIgniter version is 2.1.2

Here system library the email is send from sendmail

but I want to setup smtp globally without use of sendemail and dont want to set config parameter before send email at every place.

For overcome this issue I add email.php file on path "application\config\email.php"

Add following parameters values

```
$config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
//$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'youremailaddress@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'yourpassword';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465; 
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars'] = 76;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['validate'] = FALSE;
$config['priority'] = 3;
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;
```

but it gives me error like below
The following SMTP error was encountered:

```
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
from: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
to: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
data: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue or any other way to set smtp in global way ?

I will appreciate best answer.

Comment: So a couple of questions: 1) Does it work if you apply the config directly? I.e. when you construct the Email class? 2) Are you auto loading the config file? (i.e. application/config/autoload.php >> config ??)

Comment: thanks for your reply 

1) no it not works when I apply config directly
2) yes I have loaded email.php file in autoload.php like $autoload['config'] = array("email");

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
'protocol'  => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'smtp_port'     => 587,
'smtp_user'     => 'youremail',
'smtp_pass'     => 'yourpass',
'mailtype'      => 'html',
'smtp_crypto'   => 'tls',
'charset'       => 'iso-8859-1',
'clrf'      => "\r\n",
'newline'   => "\r\n",
```

This main parameters I need for my connections.

Comment: please,can you tell me location where to place this? here -application\config\email.php ?